# How to search something on youtube and save the seach results in notepad, all of this in background?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I want to create an application which will take a keyword as input and search that on youtube and then scrape the links and save them and in a Notepad file, and all of this works in background. I am familiar about BeautifulSoup library, and selenium but I want it to work in background unlike Selenium which works in front of us. I hope the question is clear, if not you may ask.

I am familiar about Selenium, but I want to automate the search in background.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\MyPC\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("http://www.youtube.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("search_query").send_keys("Selenium Tutorial")
driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

This code opens the browser and then performs the search, but I want everything to happen in background and fast without and delay.

Comment: You keep saying "in the background" but I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. Background of what?

Comment: You're either looking for threading, or just keep this one bit of code as its own script and launch it separately from your main script

Comment: Try headless option which will run in background.

Comment: By background, I mean that the user should not see the browser opening on his screen, rather the code should execute and he gets the notepad file in his computer.

Comment: Selenium can run browser in option `'headless'` and it will not display its window. You can also use webdrive `PhantomJS` which simulate web browser and don't display window. On Linux you could use program `Xfvb` to create fake/virtual monitor and use it run program which doesn't have option to run 'headless'

Answer (score 0):

You can run browser with option `--headless` and it will not display its window. It works for Firefox and Chrome.

Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

driver.save_screenshot('screenshot-firefox.png')
driver.close()
```

Chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--headless')
#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

driver.save_screenshot('screenshot-chrome.png')
driver.close()
```

There was webdriver PhantomJS which simulated headless web browser but it is not developed any more. This code still runs but it gives me empty `page_source`and empty file `screenshot.png`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

print(driver.page_source)

driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
driver.close()
```

---

On Linux you could use [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to create fake/virtual monitor and program can use it to display its window. This way you don't see this window on your screen.

---

All this methods has to render page so it may not run faster.

To scrape faster you would have to analyze requests/responses from/to web browser and do the same with python module `requests` - but it is not ease. But this way program doesn't have to render page and run JavaScript so it will run a lot faster.

But then you may have another problem - if you make request too offen (too fast) then server can block you and you need proxy servers to have different IPs.

Answer (score 0):

theres a workaround using pyvirtualdisplay also if you want to hide the selenium browser, dont forget to close the browse when you're done

i think webhosts can detect headless browsers, so u may get different results

stop loading the page after u get what you're looking for and/or close the browser after you save the source, insert javascript